# how assign value to a variable using anchor tag

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

i am trying to assign value to a variable in codeigniter view using anchor tag so when a user click on a specific anchor tag then a value will will be assigned but its not happening.

```
   <?php
                            $view_set = $this->session->userdata('view');

                            $gruid = '';

                            ?>

                            <label>View</label>
                            <a href="#"
                               class="view_set <?= ($view_set == 'gird') ? 'grid-list-ative' : ''; ?>"
                               data-view="gird" id="gird" onclick="<?php $gruid == 'grid' ?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                            <a href="#"
                               class="view_set <?= ($view_set == 'list') ? 'grid-list-ative' : ''; ?>"
                               data-view="list" id="list" onclick="<?php $gruid = 'listt'; ?>"><i
                                        class="fa fa-list-ul" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>


                            <?php

                            if ($gruid == null || !isset($gruid) || $gruid == 'grid') {

                                echo "i am in grid mode";

                                if (@$_GET['categories'] == '1' && @$_GET['search'] == NULL || @$_GET['categories'] == '2' && @$_GET['search'] == NULL || @$_GET['categories'] == '3' && @$_GET['search'] == NULL || @$_GET['categories'] == '5' && @$_GET['search'] == NULL || @$_GET['categories'] == '6' && @$_GET['search'] == NULL || @$_GET['categories'] == '1129' && @$_GET['search'] == NULL) {

                                    $view_set = 'gird';

                                }
                            } elseif ($gruid == 'listt') {
                                echo "i am in list mode";

                                $view_set = 'list';
                            } else {

                                echo "i am in last stage";
                                $view_set = 'list';
                            }

                            ?>
```

Comment: PHP can't listen browser events, use [URL's query parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure) instead and catch it with PHP's superglobel `$_GET`.

Comment: but on click on <a> tag on same page it doesn't show a new get parameter how can i do that so i can then use that parameter using super global $_GET

Comment: No need of new get parameter. first href  => `href="?gruid=grid"`, Second href =>  `href="?gruid=listt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not assign values to PHP variable using onClick (JavaScript Function), but it is possible to capture and set URL param through `$_GET` method.

If you are using **Codeigniter**, you must load [**CodeIgniter URL Helper Library**](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) first.

> $this->load->helper('url');

**try below,**

```
<?php


if(isset($_GET['view_set']) && $_GET['view_set'] == 'list') {
    $view_set = "list";
    echo "i am in list mode";
} else {
    $view_set = "grid";
    echo "i am in grid mode";

    if (@$_GET['categories'] == '1' && @$_GET['search'] == NULL || @$_GET['categories'] == '2' && @$_GET['search'] == NULL || @$_GET['categories'] == '3' && @$_GET['search'] == NULL || @$_GET['categories'] == '5' && @$_GET['search'] == NULL || @$_GET['categories'] == '6' && @$_GET['search'] == NULL || @$_GET['categories'] == '1129' && @$_GET['search'] == NULL) {
        $view_set = 'gird';
    }
}
?>

<label>View</label>
<a href="<?php echo current_url() ?>?view_set=grid" class="view_set <?= ($view_set == 'gird') ? 'grid-list-ative' : ''; ?>" data-view="gird" id="gird" >
    <i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
<a href="<?php echo current_url() ?>?view_set=list" class="view_set <?= ($view_set == 'list') ? 'grid-list-ative' : ''; ?>" data-view="list" id="list" >
    <i class="fa fa-list-ul" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: remain always in grid mode problem is with url on <a> click url do not change to  abc/?view=grid bt it remain the same abc.com

Comment: try changing the parameter view to view_set in <a> tag which should be like abc/?view_set =grid